# Return customers with no sales

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a bit of a beginner with SQL so apologies if this seems trivial/basic. I'm struggling to get my head around it...

I am trying to generate results that show all customers that are in the customer table that have never placed an order and will therefore have no entry on the invoice table.

In other words, I want to select all customers from the customer table where there is no entry for their customer number in the invoice table.

Many thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
           FROM invoice i
          WHERE i.customerid = c.customerid
      )
```

I would suggest you also read Oracle's documentation on different types of table joins [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm).

Comment: Thank you, this seems to get the result I wanted. Would you mind explaining why you use 'SELECT 1' - what does it mean/do?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return all customer rows, then you will want to use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
select *
from customer c
left join invoices i
  on c.customerid = i.customerid
where i.customerid is null
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd4f8/3)

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, then here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

A `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows from the `customer` table even if there is not a matching row in the `invoices` table.  If you wanted to return only the rows that matched in both tables, then you would use an `INNER JOIN`. By adding the `where i.customerid is null` to the query it will return only those rows with no match in `invoices`.

Comment: I guess he want only the customers that are not in invoices table... so you should have to check i.customerid is null on where clause... to filter, if you do the left join

Comment: @Frederic the location in the `WHERE` clause is correct - see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd4f8/3

Comment: the where clause wasnt there when I comment.. probly you were editing when I comment.. Or I am soo sleepy... anyway, nice answer BF

Answer (score 2):

if customer_id is the collumn that identify the customer you should do something like this...

```
select * from Customer
where customer_id not in (select customer_id from invoice)
```